# como obtener 'id' de una llave foranea

Tags: python, django

Buenas lo que quiero hacer es llenar una tabla que tiene un foreingkey y no se tomar el valor que guarda `id` en la base dato

```
class Reportes(models.Model):
    id_fichero=models.ForeignKey(Cargar_Fichero)
    # file=models.FileField(null=True)
    serial=models.IntegerField(null=False,default=1)
    day=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    log_source=models.CharField(null=False,max_length=50)
    event_code=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    entyti_type=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    entyti_value=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    action=models.TextField(null=False)
    computer=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    user=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    user_role=models.CharField(max_length=100)                                    


class Alarmas(models.Model):
    llave=models.ForeignKey(Reportes)
    nombre=models.CharField(null=False,max_length=50)
    eliminada=models.IntegerField(null=False,max_length=50)
    investigada=models.IntegerField(null=False,max_length=50)
    asignada=models.IntegerField(null=False,max_length=50)
    rol=models.CharField(null=False,max_length=50)
```

Answer (score 2):

Pues con el `id`. Por ejemplo, para conocer el `id` del campo `llave` del modelo `Alarmas` solo tienes que hacer:

```
alarma = Alarmas.objects.get(pk=1)
alarma.llave        // para obtener el objeto Reporte relacionado
alarma.llave.id     // para obtener el id del objeto Reporte relacionado.
```

Comment: lo que necesito es conocer el "id" de la tabla reporte que se guarda en la base de datos.

Comment: Eso es lo que estoy contestando. El modelo `Reportes` crea una tabla que se llama `reportes` que se relaciona con el campo `llave` del modelo `Alarmas`. ¿Te refieres al `id` de un registro en particular?

Comment: el problema es el siguiente las tablas en la base dato crea un id dinamico llamado llave y si es una foranea lo llama id_llave_id eso es lo que tiene la tabla alarma y yo quiero el id o mejor dicho la llave de la tabla reportes.Lo probe creandolo asi: Reportes.object.get(id(Reportes)) y no funciono.

Comment: Opino que no deberías preocuparte por cómo se llaman las tablas o los campos de las tablas en Django, para eso existe el Gestor de Objetos Relacionales de Django que funciona de manera prácticamente idéntica en cualquier motor de base de datos. Te recomiendo que consultes la documentación sobre los [campos relacionados](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/topics/db/queries/#backwards-related-objects) y de ser necesario reformula tu pregunta.

Comment: esta fue la solucion que encontre: alarama.llave= re donde re es una instancia de la clase Reportes

Comment: Bien. Igual que mi respuesta. Felicidades.

Answer (score 0):

Siguiendo la lógica de toledano, la última línea quedaría así para obtener el id:
alarma.llave__id. Utilizando <__> accedes a todos ls atributos del objeto llave.